# MySQL save file from remote server

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My question is give it a way to save a sql result from a remote server to a local file ? i open the phpmyadmin over the browser from the server and run this command as example:

```
SELECT id,ordernumber FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.txt'
```

this saves a file on the server but can i save this file to my local pc ?

Answer (score 0):

If you dump the output to the screen instead of the file you could save the output from phpmyadmin.

1. Execute your sql query in the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin.
2. After execution, scroll down the page and look for “Query results operations”
3. Click “Export” link from the above and you will get the page to export all the results of the queries to desired format.